# Can I install 2 magento different version in single system

Tags: magento2, installation

I installed magento 2.0.0 in debian jessie via vagrant, I need to install magento 2.0.1 in same vagrant, It Possible?, if Possible suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Just install in different folder  like 2.0.0, 2.0.5, ...

Magento2 use only folders inside magento_root by default so no problem here